# std::transform on vectors of Armadillo vectors

Tags: c++, vector, armadillo

I have 2 `std::vector< arma::rowvec::fixed<3> >` and I would like to concatenate each element of these 2 vectors together so that I end up with an `std::vector< arma::rowvec::fixed<3> >`. No problem with using a for loop to achieve that with `arma::join_horiz()`, but I have some difficulties when trying to use `std::transform` instead of the for loop. I tried different solutions, but always end up with some compilation errors :

First attempt :

```
// Create dummy vectors
arma::rowvec::fixed<3> A, B, C, D;
A << 1 << 2 << 3 << arma::endr;
B << 4 << 5 << 6 << arma::endr;
C << 7 << 8 << 9 << arma::endr;
D << 10 << 11 << 12 << arma::endr;

std::vector< arma::rowvec::fixed<3> > AB;
AB.push_back(A);
AB.push_back(B);
std::vector< arma::rowvec::fixed<3> > CD;
CD.push_back(C);
CD.push_back(D);

// Concatenate 1
std::vector< arma::rowvec::fixed<6> > concat;
std::transform(AB.begin(), AB.end(), CD.begin(), concat.begin(), arma::join_horiz< arma::rowvec::fixed<3>, arma::rowvec::fixed<3> >());
```

Compilation output :

```
./armadillo_test/main.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
../armadillo_test/main.cpp:81:87: error: no matching function for call to 'join_horiz()'
../armadillo_test/main.cpp:81:87: note: candidate is:
/usr/local/include/armadillo_bits/fn_join.hpp:53:1: note: template<class T1, class T2> const arma::Glue<T1, T2, arma::glue_join> arma::join_horiz(const arma::Base<typename T1::elem_type, T1>&, const arma::Base<typename T1::elem_type, T2>&)
```

Second attempt based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675930/boost-tuple-transform):

```
typedef const arma::Glue< arma::rowvec::fixed<3>, arma::rowvec::fixed<3>, arma::glue_join > (*join_ft) (const arma::Base< arma::rowvec::fixed<3>::elem_type, arma::rowvec::fixed<3> >&, const arma::Base< arma::rowvec::fixed<3>::elem_type, arma::rowvec::fixed<3> >&);
join_ft join_fptr = &arma::join_horiz;
std::transform(AB.begin(), AB.end(), CD.begin(), concat.begin(), join_fptr);
```

Compilation output :

```
from ../armadillo_test/main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algo.h: In function '_OIter std::transform(_IIter1, _IIter1, _IIter2, _OIter, _BinaryOperation) [with _IIter1 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<arma::Row<double>::fixed<3u>*, std::vector<arma::Row<double>::fixed<3u> > >, _IIter2 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<arma::Row<double>::fixed<3u>*, std::vector<arma::Row<double>::fixed<3u> > >, _OIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<arma::Row<double>::fixed<6u>*, std::vector<arma::Row<double>::fixed<6u> > >, _BinaryOperation = const arma::Glue<arma::Row<double>::fixed<3u>, arma::Row<double>::fixed<3u>, arma::glue_join> (*)(const arma::Base<double, arma::Row<double>::fixed<3u> >&, const arma::Base<double, arma::Row<double>::fixed<3u> >&)]':
../armadillo_test/main.cpp:85:79:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algo.h:4920:2: error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'const arma::Base<double, arma::Row<double>::fixed<3u> >&' from expression of type 'arma::Row<double>::fixed<3u>'
```

I guess that the types/templates I'm using when calling `arma::join_horiz` are wrong, but I can't figure out the right syntax. Any idea ?